# Automatic VPN reconnection on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-task-scheduler

I work on my office computer (OC) from home throw TeamViewer. OC connect to the Internet through VPN using standard windows tools. Sometimes after hours VPN server can be reloaded or fail, I don't know. Anyway, OC loses connection with it and consequently with Internet so I need OC to automatically reconnect to the server. How to do that using Windows Task scheduler? Thanks.

Comment: Google Windows 10 always on VPN. It’s a new feature of Windows VPN that addresses this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create task which runs on startup:

```
cmd /c "for /l %x in (0,0,0) do (rasdial SmartVPN Login Pass & timeout 5)"
```

It will be trying to reсonnect when computer lost internet connection.

But I think it's possible to change trigger to another condition - to run the task when there is no user activity (system idle).